# Use of -ing in certain sentences

Tags: gerunds

The following sentence is very common in employment and reply letters:

*I look forward **to hearing** from you soon.*

I wonder why "to hear" must not/cannot be used instead.

What's the rule behind the use of the gerund (is that really the gerund?) in sentences like the above?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just one of those expressions. You have to use a noun after look(ing) forward to.

Comment: Note that the "to" in "look forward to" doesn't function like the "to" that marks infinitives (as in "I want to hear from you").  You could also say "I look forward to the revolution," but you cannot say "*I want to the revolution"; rather, you have to say "I want the revolution."

Comment: I suspect that this a dup...

Answer (score 1):

You look forward to *something*. "Something" here is a noun, the object of the preposition "to." "Hearing," in your example, is indeed a gerund, which behaves as a noun. "Hear" is not a noun, it is a verb--verbs are never objects. Only a noun can be an object. Hence, "hearing."

Another explanation that is sometimes offered is that "look forward to" is a transitive verb, which requires a direct object. I am less inclined to that view, as the presence of the preposition indicates an indirect object rather than a direct object. However, with either explanation, the object must be a noun.

Comment: And you could say *I want to hear from you soon* where *want* is transitive. *I want hearing from you soon* is possible but a bit odd. Though *hope*, which is intransitive goes the other way.